# Catch/try not working for input mismatch exception with scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, biginteger, inputmismatchexception

Alright so I'm taking a CS security class that has some basic java programing in it and our first assignment is to play with `BigInteger`. However, we also have to "bullet proof" our program. And while my method isn't the most ideal, it works EXCEPT for the first input. Aka if I type in an invalid input for any of the `input.new---();` my program will prompt the user to try again with valid numbers. But the first `input.nextInt();` will still take invalid input and crash, displaying the `"java.util.InputMismatchException"` and then rambles on about scanner. Any ideas as to why this is happening?
p.s. The program must not display an error log under any circumstances.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class BigNumber{
   public static void main(String args[]){

     while(true){ 
      try{
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("if you wish to exit the program type in '0,' to continue running the program type in any other value: ");
         double esc= input.nextDouble();
         if(esc == 0){ break;}
         else{System.out.println("Ok, program running...");}
         input.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter number a: ");
         String aValue = input.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter number b: ");
         String bValue = input.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter a number 'n': ");
         String nValue = input.nextLine();
         while (Integer.parseInt(nValue) < 1)
         {
            if (Integer.parseInt(nValue) < 1)
            {
               System.out.print("Please enter a valid number (n>1): ");
               nValue = input.nextLine();
            }
         }

         BigInteger a= new BigInteger(aValue);
         BigInteger b= new BigInteger(bValue);
         BigInteger n= new BigInteger(nValue);

         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         System.out.println("1) a xor b: " + a.xor(b));
         System.out.println("2) b xor b: " + b.xor(b));
         System.out.println("3) a xor b xor a: " + a.xor(b).xor(a));
         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("4) ab mod n: " + a.modPow(b,n));
         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("5) a shifted to the right by 6: " + a.shiftRight(6));
         System.out.println("6) b shifted to the left by 3: " + b.shiftLeft(3));
         System.out.println("---------------------------");

      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println("-----> Please try entering a valid number(s) <-----");
      }

    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle says

> **public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException**
>   Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.
>
> **public class NumberFormatException extends IllegalArgumentException**
>   Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

you used only `NumberFormatException`in the catch block so it only catch the `NumberFormatException`. To catch other exception you have to add other catch block

```
catch (NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println("-----> Please try entering a valid number(s) <-----");
catch (InputMismatchException e){
         System.out.println("-----> Please try entering a valid number(s) <-----");
```

OR
if you used base Exception class it will catch any kind of Exception

```
catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("-----> Please try entering a valid number(s) <-----");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `catch` block only handles `NumberFormatException`. If you're trying to handle all `Exception`(s) then I suggest you change this

```
catch (NumberFormatException e){
```

to something like

```
catch (Exception e){
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextDouble()` will read double value. If parseDouble fails, a `InputMismatchException` is thrown.

Here the code of the class:

```
public double nextDouble() {
    // Check cached result
    if ((typeCache != null) && (typeCache instanceof Double)) {
        double val = ((Double)typeCache).doubleValue();
        useTypeCache();
        return val;
    }
    setRadix(10);
    clearCaches();
    // Search for next float
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(processFloatToken(next(floatPattern())));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token
        throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`InputMismatchException` and `NumberFormatException` are different classes. there is no relationship between them,your program throws `InputMismatchException` and you are trying to catch `NumberFormatException`. You will need one more catch block for `InputMismatchException` exception.